# Reading png images with gil

Tags: c++, boost, boost-gil

Is it possible with `boost::gil` to read the RGB image information so that I can read the file into the correct `rgbx_image_t`?

With the following I have to know the type beforehand and that is not so neat.

```
boost::gil::rgb8_image_t im;
gil::png_read_image(m_filename, im);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a list of types you want to try and use an `any_image` to hold a type-erased result:

```
typedef mpl::vector<rgb8_image_t, rgb16_image_t> my_img_types;
any_image<my_img_types> runtime_image;
png_read_image("input.png", runtime_image);
```

[Source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/gil/doc/html/giltutorial.html#DynamicImageSec)

Answer (score 3):

Alternative to the introducing any_image runtime stuff is using *_read_and_convert_image functions family (png_read_and_convert_image for your case)